# Generate a random point within a rectangle (uniformly)

Tags: algorithm, random, geometry, 2d, distribution

Generate a random point within a rectangle (uniformly)

This suppose to be a simple problem.

However, in [RANDOM_DATA homepage](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/random_data/random_data.html) I found the following note:

> However, we will not achieve uniform distribution in the simple case
>   of a rectangle of nonequal sides [0,A] x [0,B], if we naively scale
>   the random values (u1,u2) to (A*u1,B*u2). In that case, the expected
>   point density of a wide, short region will differ from that of a
>   narrow tall region. The absence of uniformity is most obvious if the
>   points are plotted.

I found it quite of strange... I can't figure out why such scaling will affect the uniformity.

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

Thank you Patrick87 and missingno. I was searching for a theoretical reason for the statement. I now understand that **the reason is not theoretical, but practical - the granularity of floating-point values**.

If I'll generate two uniform floating-points between 0 and 1 (which is an issue by itself due to the nature of floating-point value representation. Look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/moler/random.pdf) for an algorithm) - the granularity will be limited.

Suppose that there are X different values between 0 and 1. By scaling (u1,u2) to (u1,2*u2) we'll have X different values in the range [0,u1] and X different values in the range [0,2*u2]. For area uniformity we should have twice as many different values in [0,2*u2] than in [0,u1].

Given that, Allow me to change my question:

**How should I generate a random point within a rectangle (with uniform distribution by area)?**

Comment: This is a non-issue if you define a lattice (even a very fine one) and choose random integer coordinates for points. It's a question of granularity.

Comment: There's no problem with floating-point granularity or something.

Comment: If there was no word "random" in the quote, I could presume that they're talking about generating of a uniform grid and not about random variables' distributions, but as this word is there, I cannot.

Comment: Correct. The lattice solution addresses this directly by ensuring that the number of possibilities in each dimension is roughly in proportion to the length of the interval over which it is uniformly ranging... so there really are twice as many distinct values in the X-dimension, if the rectangle is twice as wide as it is tall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How should I generate a random point within a rectangle (with uniform distribution by area)?**

This should work:

```
  // given A, B, dimensions of rectangle
  // given g, granularity of shorter side

  if A > B then
     bm := g
     am := floor(g * A / B)
  else then
     am := g
     bm := floor(g * B / A)

  for i := 1 to n do
     av := A * RandomInt(0..am) / am
     bv := B * RandomInt(0..bm) / bm
     print (av, bb)
```

EDIT: A simpler alternative would be to simply scale random floating point values by the same factor, choose points at random, and throw away points that fall outside your rectangle. However, you don't know how many trials you'd need before you got N points in the rectangle...

Comment: interesting. Can you define _granularity_ precisely?

Comment: oh, never mind, I think I got it. But this is insignificant for floats, I guess. `g` for `float`s should be so little I would be afraid to multiply numbers by it :)

Comment: The idea is to define an integer lattice of dimensions am x bm, where am/bm ~ A/B. Granularity is then defined to be the number of distinct lattice coordinates in the smaller dimension, so that you are guaranteed to have at least g^2 distinct lattice points to choose from.

Comment: Ok, now I see that this is just complete nonsense. This is not what was discussed on RANDOM_DATA and this is something really bad. Can you give the value of `g` for `float` and A = 3, B = 7, for example? This is not going to be any better than scaling, I bet on worse.

Comment: This has nothing to do with floating-point numbers... there is no g that makes this scheme the same as floating-point. Floating point numbers work completely differently. For A = 7, B = 3, a g of 3,000,000 would result in am=7,000,000 bm=3,000,000 and 21x10^12 unique grid points (when converted to floats, there can be rounding, but that's unavoidable) which are equally likely...

Comment: but then how can it be an answer to the question? Op clearly states that this is about floating point values :) I just don't understand why are you telling this. Was it used in some real code as I can't imagine it?

Comment: Points are selected on the huge integer lattice, and then these are scaled down to the rectangle. This is a little different from choosing a floating-point between 0 and 1 and scaling up. Why offer this? If the OP is worried about floating point scaling not being uniform, this provides a method which clearly does not suffer from any such problem. If that's not clear to you, I can try to clarify the approach. I think there might be something to the OP's doubt regarding the granularity of FPs affecting uniformity under uneven scaling.

Comment: No, I understand the solution itself, I just doubt its practical usefulness. For example, it's possible to define uniformity such that your solution will be actually solving the task, but it's something different to what I consider "uniformly distributed `float`".

Comment: How would you define "uniform"? My solution gives a discrete distribution, but so does FP; my solution gives points at only specific, finite, predefined possibilities, but so does FP; etc. The only benefit of doing it my way is that you put off rounding to the last step, so you get less accumulated error... meaning that we can distinguish more numbers.

Comment: but your solution cannot return nearly as many different points as FP at least because of ` am := floor(g * A / B)` being some crazy big number in this situation. Ok, I guess it's enough of arguments, everyone can choose appropriate approach for himself.

Comment: @unkulunkulu: there are indeed two different meanings to "uniformaly distributed float". The 1st is the mathematical definition (given float=real), as in wikipedia's artice "Uniform distribution (continuous)". The 2nd is as shown in figure 9.1 in the mathworks' PDF attached to my question. Here I assume that my random generator generates something that is as similar as it can be to the mathematical definition.

Comment: @Lior, that second definition is a joke-definition which is far from mathematical, of course, we're not talking about selection all `float` bit-patterns uniformly, obviously. I'm just advocating that this answer is overcomplicated and actually much worse than scaling for example `drand48` output, 'cause for possible values of 'g' it will generate points with too big gaps. It will be uniform in some sense, but not too dense, which is bad, because you get less different random values.

Comment: Getting maximal density AND uniform area density is impossible when using discrete values over non-square areas. The OP wants uniform density by area in such regions; ergo the density cannot be maximal.

Comment: There are 53 bits in doubles; so 2^106 pairs of doubles in [0, 1). Using random 64-bit longs can therefore do as good or better than doubles (around 2^120 in good cases), limited only by the shape of the region (assuming uniform area density trumps peak density).

Comment: Generally speaking, what are good values for granularity for practical purposes?

Answer (score 5):

That statement is incorrect, direct product of two independent uniform measures is a uniform measure. This can be shown as follows:

A probability for a random point to hit a rectangle with sides `a` and `b` is equal to probability for the first coordinate to hit the segment with the length `a` and the second coordinate to hit the segment with the length `b`. (We are talking about projections of a rectangle to axes).

First probability is `a / A`, the second one is `b / B`.
As these variables are independent, the probabilities multiply, so the resulting probability is `ab / AB`, so we have a uniform 2D distribution as the probability is proportional to the area of the rectangle. This formula is symmetric with respect to `a` and `b`, so the observation in the quote is wrong about narrow and wide rectangles.

Comment: +1. A simple argument based on their own example shows you are right. 1/(nm) of points will fall in a rectangle of dimensions (A/n)x(B/m). Clearly, the same is true of rectangles (A/m)x(B/n). These rectangles have the same area and same number of points, so same density by area.

Comment: @Patrick, although it is obvious, I drew two rectangles on the paper before answering :D

Answer (score 2):

Ascii art:

Take a 3x3 rectangle:

```
***
***
***
```

And spread one of the sides by 3x:

```
*..*..*..*
*..*..*..*
*..*..*..*
```

You can kind of see here that the points are more densely packed vertically than they are horizontaly. What you actually want instead is uniform distribution *by area*

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to handle this is through rejection sampling:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling

```
// Given dimensions of the rectangle A, B where A <= B
boolean flag = true
while (flag) do:
  double a = NextRandomDouble(0,B)
  double b = NextRandomDouble(0,B)
  if (a <= A)
    return(a, b)
  else
    next
```

You essentially generate uniform numbers from a square that fits the original rectangle (of length B, in this example). If the number falls in the rectangle, keep the pair. If it does not, throw it away and try again!